# EJB not found between two Webspheres

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, ibm-was

I have j2ee application running on WAS 8.5. There are two war files and I need to use ejb between them. 
When I run my application on single WAS everything works fine but I have to distribute my application on two WAS servers and with this setup I got following exception

```
org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
```

However I can run test from my local machine to one of WAS server and everything works fine.

Where can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your JNDI tree and the way you're invoking your remote EJB?

Comment: The problem is two WAS instances have same name. This is knows issue. Now I need to rename one of them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websphere 6.1: Issue in Multiple Cells Call using IIOP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032922/websphere-6-1-issue-in-multiple-cells-call-using-iiop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is two WAS instances have same name. This is knows issue. Now I need to rename one of them